# Closure of a given set in metric space with euclidean metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a short question. Consider $(X,d)$ - metric space, where $X=(0,1)\times[0,1)$ and d - euclidean metric. $B = \{\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,...\} \times (0,1)$ is a given set. So $Int B = \emptyset$, and $cl B=\{\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,...\} \times [0,1)$ or $cl B=\{0,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,...\} \times [0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\widetilde{X}=[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Then $X\subset \widetilde{X}$. 
Denote $B_1:=\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\}$ and $B_2:=[0,1)$. First we compute the closure of $B_1$ and $B_2$ with respect to $\widetilde{X}$. Notice that $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $x_n:=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geqslant 2$ is in $B_1$. If $\bar{B}_1$ denotes the closure of $B_1$ then by definition it must be that $\lim_n x_n\in\bar{B}_1$ i.e. $\lim_n=\frac{1}{n}=0\in\bar{B}_1$. This is the only limit point of any sequence in $B_1$ since any sequence is nothing but a subsequence of $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Therefore $\bar{B}_1=\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\}\cup \{0\}$. Now consider $B_2$. Let $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $y_n:=1-\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geqslant 2$. Then it is easy that for all $n$ we have $y_n\in B_2$. By the definition of closure again it must be the case that $\lim_ny_n\in\bar{B}_2$ i.e. $\lim_n(1-\frac{1}{n})=1\in\bar{B}_2$. Since any sequence in $B_2$ must have nonnegative terms strictly less than $1$ then we can conclude that the only limit points added to $B_2$ is $1$. Hence $\bar{B}_2=[0,1]$. Now using $\overline{B_1\times B_2}=\bar{B}_1\times\bar{B}_2$ it follows $\overline{B_1\times B_2}=(\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\}\cup \{0\})\times[0,1]$. However we need the closure of $B_1\times B_2$ computed in $X$ which we denote by $(\overline{B_1\times B_2})_X$. This can be computed by the following equation 
$$(\overline{B_1\times B_2})_X=X\cap\overline{B_1\times B_2}=(\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\})\times[0,1)$$
$$$$

Comment: edit it. thought it was the closed unit square.

Answer (score 0):

Use the theorem cl A×B = (cl A) × (cl B).